# stacked barplot of age proportions

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
region   age   total     p
<fct>    <fct> <int> <dbl>
SSC20005 < 40     16 0.485
SSC20005 >=40     17 0.515
SSC20012 < 40    247 0.581
SSC20012 >=40    178 0.419
SSC20018 < 40     50 0.5  
SSC20018 >=40     50 0.5
```

I'm looking to create a stacked barplot for each region filled by the column "p", so that the bar height = 1.

I've tried using

```
ggplot(data = cbind(id = 1,age_prop), aes(x = id, fill = p)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Age Bracket", y = "Proportion")
```

However, I keep getting error message saying

> Error: Argument 2 must be length 1, not 1000
> (1000 is relating to my local dataset, the error here would rather be length 6)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to `fill` by `p` or `age` ? Try :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = region, y = p, fill = age)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + 
  labs(x = "Age Bracket", y = "Proportion")
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(region = c("SSC20005", "SSC20005", "SSC20012", 
"SSC20012", "SSC20018", "SSC20018"), age = c("<40", ">=40", "<40", 
">=40", "<40", ">=40"), total = c(16L, 17L, 247L, 178L, 50L, 
50L), p = c(0.485, 0.515, 0.581, 0.419, 0.5, 0.5)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: what you've done here is great. Why would I be getting: "Error in .Call.graphics(C_palette2, .Call(C_palette2, NULL)) : 
  invalid graphics state"?

Comment: I don't receive any such error. I think this is some kind of installation/library error. Can you try restarting R/R studio and try again? If you still face the error can you try with the dataset in my post and check if it works for you using that data?